# Selenium (Java) - Keep clicking a button until specific text is present in an element and fail if certain amount of time is exceeded

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I can stop an engine by clicking a button which starts a background process and I can see the current status of the engine every time only after clicking a `Refresh Status` button in the page. The issue is that the time varies for the engine to stop from 30 seconds to 2 mins depending upon the load on the server. I really don't want to write a `while` loop with `Thread.sleep()` as it's a bad idea and would unnecessarily increase the test time in selenium. Is there an intuitive way to wait 20 seconds every time and click the `Refresh Status` button until `Offline` text is present in the element and have a timeout of 3 mins for this whole process?

Comment: Well if you want to wait for exactly 20 seconds using Thread.sleep is OK.

Comment: You can execute a loop with explicit wait or may be sleep of of 5-10 seconds (or 20 if you want) wait in it and put that loop inside a try block, so that it throws an exception when there is a text change from "online".In catch block you can check if text actually changed to "offline" or there was a timeout and throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `ExpectedConditions` class and override static method `textToBePresentInElementLocated` if you would see the implementation is pretty much simple:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> textToBePresentInElementLocated(
      final By locator, final String text) {

    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          String elementText = findElement(locator, driver).getText();
          return elementText.contains(text);
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.format("text ('%s') to be present in element found by %s",
            text, locator);
      }
    };
  }
```

Just add element.click() in this method to a proper place and then use your class extended class in `WebDriverWait`

Comment: One issue with this method is that it will click the element every 500ms according to the WebDriverWait docs. That's probably a little too fast for something like this.

Comment: If you use FluentWait which WebDriverWait is actually adapting, you have much more control over the polling and timeout. If you then override the apply method as suggested here you should be able to accommodate your needs. Check http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait for mord details

Comment: @JeffC. But polling interval we can specify in the constructor of webdriverwait right?

Comment: @MrunalGosar When you say "add element.click()" you mean the `Refresh status` button right? Also, wouldn't this call the `apply` method every 500ms?

Comment: Yes element.click() means your refresh button and getText of whatever element u want to check status on..Also i suggested using WebdriverWait where in you can specify the polling interval instead of 500ms and also the timeout option

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
/**
 * Attempts to stop the engine within a specified time
 * 
 * @param driver 
 *            the WebDriver instance
 * @return true if the engine has stopped, false otherwise
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public boolean StopEngine(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("stopEngineButton")).click(); // click the stop engine button

    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!found && i < 6) // 6 * 20s = 2 mins
    {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("RefreshStatus")).click(); // click the Refresh Status button
        // not sure if you need a wait here to let the statusElement update
        found = driver.findElement(By.id("statusElement")).getText().equals("Offline"); // compare the current engine status to Offline
        i++;
    }

    return found;
}
```

You could also modify this code to be more flexible by passing polling interval and timeout as parameters.

Comment: Hey, as I mentioned in the question, is this the only way it can be done? Even though my scenario is pretty generic, shouldn't there be a way that I can use extending selenium's api?